# handle account/organization destroy with multiple users, redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rails-activerecord, actioncontroller

This app has the structure of users have many organizations through memberships.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
....
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization, touch: true
    belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
..
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
...
end
```

The `Organization` can be destroyed by `owners`, attribute on `memberships`, from there call backs will take care of destroying associations.

There are `before_actions` that check `user`/`organizations` associations exists. So the moment the user hits a url with an `organization` that has been deleted, they would be redirected. But this seems wrong.

My question is while the `current_user` would follow the controller action redirect. How should the other users be handled? Should they hit the `before_actions` and let those redirects handle it? Can an `after_destroy` call back handle this; that seems like breaking the `MVC` pattern tho and then you have to deal with if the user is "on" that `organization` or another.

Hell has this been discussed and this has a name that I'm not aware of.

Much appreciated.

EDIT: Controller checks:

```
class Organizations::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :restrict_user_by_role

  protected

  def restrict_user_by_role
    if organization_set?
      if !member?
        flash[:warning] = t("restricted_roles")
        redirect_to redirect_path
      elsif !current_membership.can_view_organization?
        flash[:warning] = t("restricted_roles")
        redirect_to redirect_path
      end
    else
      id = params[:parm_passed]
      unless Membership.current_member_check(id).exists?
        flash[:warning] = t("restricted_roles")
        refresh_or_redirect_to redirect_path
        return
      else
        organization = Organization.find_by(id: id)
        set_organization(organization)
        @organization = current_organization
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`organization_set?` `current_membership` `member?` are all concerns that are set with each request, while `can_view_program?`, `Membership.current_member_check(id).exists?` are authorization checks on the model record.

This is just some of the checks, but the basic idea that is used.

Comment: There is no any controller code in your question

Comment: As option you can check in some authorization layer if user exists, organization exists, user is owner of organization. If not — show page with 403 status and message like "There is no such organization or you haven't access to it"

Comment: Updated the question with one of the basic checks that I have in place. I have set up controllers to perform like you are suggesting, i.e. if conditions and authorizations are not met, the user would be redirected. @mechnicov

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is actually a [soft-delete](https://www.jmix.io/blog/to-delete-or-to-soft-delete-that-is-the-question/)? This would let you have a separate response for deleted records. As for handling the actual authorization - this is too much complexity for a controller which is hard to test. I would really suggest you use Pundit to add a separate authorization layer which can be tested in isolation.

Comment: I have implemented a soft-delete, probably not an advanced one, but most of what the article described has been implemented. So users would be redirected, I just didn't know if letting them "fail" through these redirects was correct".  @max

Comment: Also are you say that something like this should be covered using authorization? @max

Comment: @Chrismisballs I'm saying that this is already an example of authorization - it's just lacking any kind of structure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `restrict_user_by_role` make few things (non SRP). It should only check authorization rule and redirect if it fails. It shouldn't set instance variables. If before filter redirect somewhere, main action is not executed

To simplify your code make 3 checks: presence of current user, presence of current organization, ownership of current organization by current user. If one of these conditions is false — redirect user

```rb
def restrict_user_by_role
  if current_user.nil? || current_organization.nil? || !current_organization.owners.include?(current_user)
    flash[:warning] = t("restricted_roles")
    redirect_to redirect_path
  end
end
```

Comment: While this does simplify the controller, I'm still curious if my though process about user redirects is warranted?

Comment: I think it's warranted, but it's better to use ActionPolicy or Pundit for this purpose

Comment: Ok cool, So are you say that something like this should be covered using authorization?

Comment: Yes, it's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100333/handle-account-organization-destroy-with-multiple-users-redirects/77102414?noredirect=1#comment135919404_77100333) to use separate layer for this